# OPC UA Server, how to add certificates and Encryption

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I'm new to OPC UA Server and OPC Standards. I've go through the OPC Standards and downloaded the OPC UA Server sample application and executed it. I wanted to add security certificate and encryption to OPC UA Server. I can see that

application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate method is called and

config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation += CertificateValidator_CertificateValidation event is set. But still my client call connect to OPC UA Server without any certificates.

How can I enforce the server to make a connection only a valid certificate is available and is there a possibility to encrypt the messages using the certificate.

Help and guidance on above is highly appreciated. Thanks